# How to debug Eclipse source code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I am having tough time to figure out debugging UI parts of Eclipse. I couldn't find any information on google (or) Eclipse web site.

**All I wanted to do is to find out the code that gets executed when we double-click a file in project explorer to open the file in Editor.**

I tried to bring up Eclipse source code from Plug-ins view -> right click on the plugins -> import as Source Project. But, I am unsure what are all the components that constitutes to the UI part. I get some weird errors when I try to import everything that's found in plug-ins view.

Where can I find the information related to debugging Eclipse source code?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Plug-ins->Import as Source Project`, I would recommend opening the **Plug-ins view**, selecting all plug-ins, right click, and Add to Java Search.

Then you can use Open Type `Ctrl-Shift-t` to search for class names and the source will be attached so you can read it, set breakpoints, and debug.

In your case, I think you want to investigate `IWorkbench`, `IWorkbenchWindow`, and `IWorkbenchPage`.  The `openEditor(*)` methods on `IWorkbenchPage` will be of particular interest.

You may also want to take a look at the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` and `org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes` extension points.